# Cast Future<File> to base64 image with Flutter

Tags: image, flutter, dart, base64

Hi the flutter code below loads a photo from the camera roll and then displays it, on video, what I have to do is recover the path of the file, to do it I use the code below inside the **`inserimento`** function but when I run the code I the following error:

> Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining
> a getter or field named 'path'.    print("\n Immagine:
> "+imageFile.path);

**Flutter Code:**

```
Future<File> imageFile; 

  //Costruttore 
  ArticoloEditPage(){
    aggiornaValori();
    BackButtonInterceptor.add(myInterceptor);
    setData(new DateTime.now());
  }

  //Disabilito il bottone di back su android
  bool myInterceptor(bool stopDefaultButtonEvent, RouteInfo info) {
    return true;
  }
  //Funzione di init
  void init() {
    aggiornaValori();
    BackButtonInterceptor.add(myInterceptor);
  }

  //Funzione che esegue la creazione dell'utente 
  Future<bool> inserimento(BuildContext context) async {
   print("\n Immagine: "+imageFile.path);
  // var base64File=await Supporto.castDocumentToBase64(imgPath);
   //print("\n Immagine in base64: "+imgPath);
  }
  pickImageFromGallery(ImageSource source) {
    setState(() {      
      imageFile = ImagePicker.pickImage(source: source);
    });
  }
 
  Widget showImage() {
    return FutureBuilder<File>(
      future: imageFile,
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<File> snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done &&
            snapshot.data != null) {
          return Image.file(
            snapshot.data,
            width: 300,
            height: 300,
          );
        } else if (snapshot.error != null) {
          return const Text(
            'Errore caricamento non riuscito',
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          );
        } else {
          return const Text(
            'Nessuna immagine selezionata',
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          );
        }
      },
    );
  }
```

Comment: Your variable `imageFile` is a `Future<File>`, not a `File`, so it does not have a path. go to a place in your program where the `Future` is resolved to an actual `File` and do whatever you want to do with the file.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a Future and how do I use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63017280/what-is-a-future-and-how-do-i-use-it)

Comment: @nvoigt ok but how implement load path of image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can not get path directly in future method,
so

by

**1. this you can print your path.**

```
  Future<bool> inserimento(BuildContext context) async {
    var pathData=await imageFile;
    print("\n Immagine: "+pathData.path);
  }
```

or

**2.  if you need path in widget**

```
Widget showImage() {
        return FutureBuilder<File>(
          future: imageFile,
          builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<File> snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done &&
                snapshot.data != null) {


              print("Your Path : "+snapshot.data.path);


              return Image.file(
                snapshot.data,
                width: 300,
                height: 300,
              );
            } else if (snapshot.error != null) {
              return const Text(
                'Errore caricamento non riuscito',
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              );
            } else {
              return const Text(
                'Nessuna immagine selezionata',
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              );
            }
          },
        );
      }
```

also

**3. if you need base64 image.**
then

```
Future<bool> inserimento(BuildContext context) async {
     var pathData=await imageFile;
     var base64Image = base64Encode(pathData.readAsBytesSync());

        print("\n Immagine base64Image: "+base64Image.toString());
  }
```